# Breeze / OData: orderBy "max" of two properties

Tags: odata, breeze

I'm not sure if this a breeze or an OData question: I would like to use `orderBy` but using the **max** of two properties.

So for example the following would sort the list wrongly if an animal has no height specified or a height that is smaller than the animal type's minimal height:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from("Animal").orderBy("height, toAnimalType.minimalHeight", true);
```

I'm thinking of something in the range of:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from("Animal").orderBy("max(height, toAnimalType.minimalHeight)", true);
```

I looked at the [OData functions under chapter 4.5](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) but I think it is the wrong way as A) there is no `min`/`max` and B) those are `$filter`-functions (not orderBy-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to John Papa's model factory:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var serviceId = 'model';
    angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, model);
    function model() {
        // revealing module pattern
        var entityNames = {
            client: 'Client',
            order: 'Order'

... other entity names 
        };

        var service = {
            configureMetadataStore: configureMetadataStore,
            entityNames: entityNames
        };

        return service;

        function configureMetadataStore(metadataStore) {          
            registerClient(metadataStore);
        };

        //#region Internal Methods       

        function registerClient(metadatastore) {
            metadatastore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Client', client);
            function client() {

       // add calculated 'display' property to client model
       // here is where you'd decide min or max

                Object.defineProperty(client.prototype, 'display', {
                    get: function() {
                        var cn = this.companyName;
                        var st = this.state;
                        return cn.padRight('.',60) + st;
                    }
                });
        }
```

Haven't worked with this for a couple years as I do all ng4 and Typescript now   so it may be a bit rough but might give you an idea.  Recommend the Pluralsight courses for all this stuff. See if you can find the sample code for John Papa's Hot Towel Spa for Angular on github.

Comment: This is a good idea. I guess I will have to resort to this as I'm finding no way of telling Breeze/OData/EF/SQL to sort the way I want to. I was hoping that I didn't need to do any work on the client and could just get the results sorted the way I need to. I could also just go over the resulting array and sort it "manually". **FYI:** It is Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would first look at adding a calculated column to the data as it is pulled so you can just use that column for an orderBy. Much cleaner for troubleshooting as well.

Comment: The suggestion is valid but unfortunately I'm in a platform environment which doesn't allow me to create new columns in the database. I can only configure queries. I was hoping to do this from the client side without having to involve db-admins and changing the model.

Comment: Is this Angular 2+ ?  If you are using a clientside typescript model, you could calc the property there (see the temphire example from Ideablade) and then do the sort.  If in Angular.js I think you could still do something like that in a model factory on your metadatastore.  John Papa has examples of that in his Spa framework.. (Pluralsight but think he has it out somewhere in public as well )